# Create aggregation in mongodb with spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have aggregation that works in mongo and i need to create the exact one in java with spring. I didn't find a way. Do you know if there is one?

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id : { 
                year : {$year : "$receivedDate" }, 
                month : {$month: "$receivedDate"}, 
                day : { $dayOfMonth : "$receivedDate"}
            },
            count : { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try projecting the fields first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then group by the new fields in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project()       
        .andExpression("year(receivedDate)").as("year")
        .andExpression("month(receivedDate)").as("month")
        .andExpression("dayOfMonth(receivedDate)").as("day"),
    group(fields().and("year").and("month").and("day"))     
        .count().as("count")
);
```